# Per regex last match

Tags: regex, perl

I have a program that keeps printing the number of cycles it has run to a log file. I want to retrieve the last value in the log file to find out the total number of cycles run. I'm using the following code:

```
my @cycles = $log =~ /\s+(\d+)\s+Cycles/gsm;
$run{cycles} = $cycles[-1] if @cycles;
```

Is there a perl special variable that stores the last matched value so that I can use that instead of collecting cycles in an array?

Comment: Do you mean `$1`?  Look at `perldoc perlvar` for this.  You have it captured in your regular expression, you just need to use it.

Comment: No, $1 contains the first string that matched, not the last. In my case, the regex will find several matches in the file and I want the value of the last match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative look-ahead assertion:

```
($run{cycles}) = $log =~ /\s+(\d+)\s+Cycles(?!.*\s+\d+\s+Cycles)/gsm;
```

meaning "find a sequence of digits preceded by whitespace and followed by whitespace 
and the literal `Cycles`, that is not followed by another sequence of whitespace, digits, whitespace, and the literal `Cycles`".

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
my @cycles = $log =~ /\s+(\d+)\s+Cycles/gsm;
$run{cycles} = $+ if @cycles;
```

Please note that as squiguy said, the `$1` should do the trick too (at least it works for me).

Finally, in case that you don't really need to save all the cycles in an array, but just want the last value, you can do like this:

```
($run{cycles}) = $log =~ /.+\s(\d+)\s+Cycles/s;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't advise reading the whole log file into memory, but without more information on what you are doing I can't write a proper line-by-line solution.

A regex pattern with the `/g` modifier stops at the *next* match, so you just need a `while` loop.

Note that there is no point in using the `/m` or `/s` modifiers, as all they do is modify the function of the metacharacters `^`, `$` and `.`. Since you are using none of these they are having no effect.

```
while ( $log =~ /\s+(\d+)\s+Cycles/g ) {
    $run{cycles} = $1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete. You are not showing the part of your code where you slurp your log file into $log. Assuming the name of your log file was in $logFile your question is how to improve:

```
my $log = do { local( @ARGV, $/ ) = $logFile ; <> } ;
my @cycles = $log =~ /\s+(\d+)\s+Cycles/gsm;
$run{cycles} = $cycles[-1] if @cycles;
```

The answer is to read your log file one line at a time:

```
open my $logFH,'<',$logFile
  or die "Could not open $logFile: $!";

my $cycles;
while (my $logLine = <$logFH>) {
    ($cycles) = $logLine =~ /\s+(\d+)\s+Cycles/;
}
close $logFH;

$run{cycles} = $cycles
  if $cycles;
```

This way your program is only using the space of the longest line in $logFile rather than the space of the entire file, and the space to store a single Cycle instead of all of them.

That is, the amount of I/O is the same, but the memory use is much lower.

Your original program was:

1. Open the logfile, Slurp the entire log file's contents, close the lofile
2. Find all the cycles logged
3. Use the last cycle logged, if any

This program is:

1. Open the logfile
2. Read the log file one line at a time

   - Remember the last cycle seen
3. Close the log file
4. Use the last cycle seen, if any

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [**`File::ReadBackwards`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aReadBackwards) and take the "first" matching line.

```
$bw = File::ReadBackwards->new( 'log_file' ) 
    or die "can't read 'log_file' $!" 
    ;
while( defined( $log_line = $bw->readline ) ) {
    next unless m/\s+(\d+)\s+Cycles/;
    print;
    last;
}
```

It *should* be a whole lot faster.